# Ruby regular expression groups

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to match strings that might represent ranges somewhere in a document but can't quite figure out one thing about the groups... I have this so far:

```
/(^-?[0-9]+)(\.\.+)(-?[0-9]+$)/
```

Which matches  1..10, -20...20, -01234567890...-999999999, etc. However, I want the second group ($2) to have a value ONLY if the middle was 3 digits instead of two. So I would want it to be like:

```
=~ -01234567890...-999999999
$1 = -01234567890
$2 = ...
$3 = -999999999

=~ 1..10
$1 = 1
$2 = (empty because only two dots instead of 3)
$3 = 10
```

Any way to specify this, to only make a group if it's a certain value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
(^-?[0-9]+)(?:(?:[.]{,2})|([.]{,3}))(-?[0-9]+$)
```

which will only put the result in the second group if it is three `.`.

Explanation:

- `?:` - non-capturing group.
- `|` - OR

Note that `(?:[.]{,2})` is non-capturing while `([.]{,3})` will capture the group.

Comment: Our answers were almost identical! Possibly worth explaining what `?:` is doing here

Comment: @NeilSlater - agreed.